# PDF Compressor online / software

Tags: pdf, software

I have a very large ebooks; I would like to reduce their sizes while maintaining the highest possible quality.

Is there a best PDF compressor software or online website that I can upload my private ebooks to?

Note: I'm looking for a safe website that won't share my ebooks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *best*. *Best* is subjective and dependent on various factors such as type of PDF document and acceptability of quality loss.

However, Adobe Acrobat Pro DC offers an option to *Reduce File Size*.

[image: Reduce file size option]

Similar software also offer such an option. Example: ABBYY FineReader (p. 3 of [Source](https://www.abbyy.com/media/21194/abbyy-finereader14-full-feature-list.pdf)).

[image: ABBYY FineReader 14 Reduce file size option]

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com), it's the best software for your task. You save your ebook locally, and nobody can share your ebooks.

It's available for Linux and Windows, and has many usage examples.